# how to get post by using post id in ajax wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have no experience in wordpress ajax. i am trying to get my custom post type post by using post id in ajax, but i don't know how to write function.
here is my code which i am using in functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch', 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){
    if (isset($_POST["post_id"]) && isset($_POST["post_id"]) != '') {       
      $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];


        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'sponsors');
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $post_id ); 
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </div>  
                </div>

            <?php endwhile;
        endif;

    }

}
```

and here is my ajax code

```
    <a href="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" id="click_me" >Fetch Data</a>
    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '#click_me', function() {
    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost/verturesort/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'data_fetch',
            'post_id' : post_id
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            jQuery('#datainsert').append( response );
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Your browser code is performing a GET, while your back end code is looking for form data from a POST.

Comment: yes i tried it but when i use post in ajax it shows all posts.

Comment: You are not using your `$args` in your `new WP_query()`

Comment: yes i did but it sends me all posts of the sponsors

Comment: your next problem seems to be here: `isset($_POST["post_id"]) && isset($_POST["post_id"]) != ''` - the second shouldn't be wrapped in isset, I think.